# How can I make a website only viewable on a UIWebView and not anywhere else?

Tags: php, html, ios, uiwebview

So I have a UIWebView in my app that loads a website I made. So it's loading web files not local files.

How can I make it so that this website cannot be viewable on any iPhone internet browsers, but can be viewable on my UIWebView.

Comment: check browser..... and stop view.....

Answer (score 0):

Code for get browser deatils...

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\n\n";

$browser = get_browser(null, true);
print_r($browser);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to check uiwebview,otheriOS browsers and not iOS browsers,

```
  <div id="where-am-i"></div>
    <script>
        var standalone = window.navigator.standalone,
            userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(),
            safari = /safari/.test( userAgent ),
            ios = /iphone|ipod|ipad/.test( userAgent );

        if( ios ) {

            if ( !standalone && safari ) {

                document.getElementById( 'where-am-i' ).textContent = 'browser';

            } else if ( standalone && !safari ) {

                document.getElementById( 'where-am-i' ).textContent = 'standalone';

            } else if ( !standalone && !safari ) {

                document.getElementById( 'where-am-i' ).textContent = 'uiwebview';

            };
    </script>
```

Comment: What does standalone do, and can I use php to do this?

Comment: Yes you can use it in your code. http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1950-Detecting-iPhone-s-App-Mode-Full-Screen-Mode-For-Web-Applications.htm